# Проблема с базой данных на хостинге beget. Django, MySQLdb

Tags: python, django

Подключение к бд не работает выходит ошибка вот log error.
До всего этого установил библеотеку mysqlclient.

```
146019-Traceback (most recent call last):
146020:  File &quot;/home/a/amirmyks/amirmyks.beget.tech/djangoenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py&quot;, line 18, in &lt;module&gt;
146021-    from . import _mysql
146022:ImportError: cannot import name &apos;_mysql&apos; from partially initialized module &apos;MySQLdb&apos; (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/a/amirmyks/amirmyks.beget.tech/djangoenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py)
```

В файле settings.py прописал подключение к бд,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'amirmyks_django2',
        'USER': 'amirmyks_django2',
        'PASSWORD': 'zAaf9vyd',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Попробывал установить `pip install django mysqlclient` вышла ошибка

```
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./djangoenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.1.3)
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 in ./djangoenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dja
ngo) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./djangoenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from djang
o) (0.4.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-build-env-abavaeqk/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml
.py:66: _BetaConfiguration: Support for `[tool.setuptools]` in `pyproject.toml` is still *beta*.
        config = read_configuration(filepath, True, ignore_option_errors, dist)
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      # Options for building extention module:
        extra_compile_args: ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-std=c99']
        extra_link_args: ['-lmysqlclient']
        define_macros: [('version_info', (2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)), ('__version__', '2.2.0')]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      copying src/MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      copying src/MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      copying src/MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      copying src/MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      copying src/MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      copying src/MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      copying src/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
      copying src/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
      copying src/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
      copying src/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
      copying src/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
      copying src/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
      copying src/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb/constants
      running egg_info
      writing src/mysqlclient.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/mysqlclient.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src/mysqlclient.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src/mysqlclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/MySQLdb
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/MySQLdb
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC "-Dversion_info=(2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)" -D__version__=2.2.0 -I/home/a/amirmyks/amirmyks.beget.tech/djangoenv/include -I/home/a/amirmyks/.local/include/python3.9 -c src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -I/usr/include/mysql -std=c99
      error: command 'gcc' failed: Permission denied
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based proj
ects
```

как решить проблему ?